# Using Python to compare 2 lists and get the corresponding items

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, arraylist

I have two columns, one contains text strings and the other contains the time at which these text strings appear. In the example below, you will see that the texts will appear with time but will then disappear one by one while new texts being added.
[Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVE2p.jpg)

```
Time (s)    Text string
5   This example
7   This example
10  example
11  example is cool
15  is cool
16  cool
17  
19  That example is
20  example is
21  is awesome
23  awesome
24
```

I want to extract the disappeared time of each text. For example, here is what it should look like:
[Here is the result I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QUuC.jpg)

```
Disappeared time (s)    Text
10  This
15  example
16  is
17  cool
20  That
21  example
23  is
24  awesome
```

How can I write a python code to do this. I am a beginner at python, so code samples and problem solving ideas are helpful. 
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I have not been able to think of any workflow that makes sense. However, jezrael's solution works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

- [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) for indicator `DataFrame`
- create mask for select all values after last `1`
- apply [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) for convert `False`s to `NaN`s
- reshape by [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html)
- data cleaning - [`rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html), [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html)

---

```
df = df.set_index('Time (s)')['Text string'].str.get_dummies(' ')
print (df)
          That  This  awesome  cool  example  is
Time (s)                                        
5            0     1        0     0        1   0
7            0     1        0     0        1   0
10           0     0        0     0        1   0
11           0     0        0     1        1   1
15           0     0        0     1        0   1
16           0     0        0     1        0   0
17           0     0        0     0        0   0
19           1     0        0     0        1   1
20           0     0        0     0        1   1
21           0     0        1     0        0   1
23           0     0        1     0        0   0
24           0     0        0     0        0   0

df1 = (df.where(df.ne(df.shift().bfill()) & df.eq(0))
        .stack()
        .rename_axis(('Disappeared time (s)','Text'))
        .reset_index()
        .drop(0, axis=1))
print (df1)
   Disappeared time (s)     Text
0                    10     This
1                    15  example
2                    16       is
3                    17     cool
4                    20     That
5                    21  example
6                    23       is
7                    24  awesome
```

Comment: It worked! You are such a genius man! Can you explain a bit about the line of code for df1?

Comment: Thanks. I accepted but could not up vote since I am new to stackoverflow, but really appreciate your answer. Also, can you explain what this does "df.ne(df.shift().bfill()) & df.eq(0)"?

Comment: Sure, is is same like `df != (df.shift().bfill())` compare all values of Dataframe by shifted DataFrame, `bfill` is for replace first `NaN`s row by values of second row.  `df.eq(0)` means `df == 0` and `&` between is logica and - chaining.

Comment: Ah, I got the main idea. However, I just realized that my problem is a little bit more complex since each word just does not disappear the whole thing like what I showed in the example, but instead dissappearing by letter/letters. For example, between time 7 and 10s, there are "8": his example, "9": s example, and then at the "10" second: example. So it seems not possible to apply your approach, right?

Comment: Yes, it is more complicated.Can you create new question? Now I am going to bed, but if get no answer, I try get solution.

Comment: Sure. Thanks Jezrael. G9

Comment: But small advice - add some code to your question or add link to this answer for avoiding downvotes ;)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It is sad that the down-vote stops me from being able to ask a follow-up question. So, I had to ask it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48697855/python-compare-two-lists-or-two-dataframe-fields-and-return-the-disappeared-tim). You seem to be really good at this one. So please help me with a solution if you have some time. Many thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. I check your new problem and I am a bit confused. Is expected output correct? e.g is=16, cool=17, awesome=24. Can you explain why this solution cannot be used, maybe changing better sample data? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry Jezrael, I did not see your question. I was using the other account. Yes, the result is correct since I want to extract the time the words start to disappear instead of the time it completely disappear as in the previous example.

Comment: Jezrael: Any suggestion on how I can solve my problem?

Comment: @DanielNg - too complicated, because need some fuzzy matching :( And I have no idea how is possible solve it. Sorry :(

Comment: Thanks Jezrael! I guess I have to give it up then :(

Comment: Unfortunately I forget give you comment :(

Comment: Thanks, if anytime you can think of a solution that is worthy of trying, please do share with me. Anyway, you are still a genius. Thank you for helping out!